# Joint Probability Density Function of a Sample of A Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is the question: Suppose that a random variable is normally distributed with mean $μ$ and variance $σ^2,$ and we draw a random sample of five observations from this distribution. What is the joint probability density function of the sample?

I have attached the probability density function of a sample of a normal distribution,  however I am not sure how to go about this question. Thanks it advance! [image]

Comment: You seemed to have answered your own question with $n=5$. So if not, then what is your question?

Comment: is $\sigma$ also known? ($\mu$ is known, right?)

Comment: no other parameters are known. After substituting 5 for n in the formula,I am still faced with the summation of X_i.

Comment: As user2566092 said, you have already answered the question. The joint probability density function is a function of the $x_i$; there is no need to eliminate them or their summation (nor would it be possible to do so).